# Boost converter vout not boosting

Tags: boost

I am working on dc to dc boost converter using IC LED5000.
schematic design and components as per E-Design suite from ST microelectronics.
specifications are
Vin- 12V DC
Vout- 36V, 100mA
FSW- 800KHz

when i supply 12v vin my output not boosting upto 36v it is only 11to12v as vin same.
IC switching at 820KHz ok .

any suggestion..? [image]

Comment: Have you made any other connections (like a scope probe)  to GND? The device GND in this circuit must be left floating (there's a reason this is called "floating boost" in the app notes... )

Comment: no i havnt made any other GND i know it is floating boost.

Comment: Sorry but had to cover that base first since the question is so sketchy. You really haven't told us anything about what you've tested so far, have you looked at SW waveforms, or measured the chip's GND vs actual GND for example?

Comment: @BrianDrummond for your information i have checked SW oin waveform which shows 800kHZ, Boot pin shows 12V, measured with respect to Chip gnd.